# Comparing compass bearings

Tags: mathematics, bearing, map-matching, compass

I have several compass bearings:

```
bTrue = 190°
b1 = 250°
b2 = 100°
b3 = 170°
b4 = 90°
```

I want to compare b1 - b4 and find out how close they are to bTrue. So bTrue is 100%. How much percent is then b1, b2, b3, and b4? 360°-180° would be 0%.

The use case is that have GPS locations with bearings that I am trying to match to road segments, where I also know the bearing. Besides the distance to the road I also want to consider bearing. b1 - b4 are the bearings of the road and bTrue is the bearing of the GPS point.

Comment: Is the scale linear (so 90° off would be 50%)? Are the bearings all in the range [0...360]? If so, it should just be `1 - abs(bTrue - bx)/180`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the scale is linear (i.e. 0° difference between actual and desired is 100%, 90° difference between actual and desired is 50%, 180° difference between actual and desired is 0%) and that the bearings are all in the range 0...360, then you can calculate this with:

`1 - abs(bTrue - bx)/180`

where `bTrue` is the desired bearing (course) and `bx` is one of the candidate options.